# benefit of irreversible migration in Active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have been reading Active record migrations in rails. It's likely we are going to make reversible migrations most of the time, but I don't  understand what is the point of making irreversible  migrations? Can anyone give some examples? And what's the benefit  of making them irreversible?

This is what I read from rails Guide:

```
class ChangeProductsPrice < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      change_table :products do |t|
        dir.up   { t.change :price, :string }
        dir.down { t.change :price, :integer }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a column named `zipcode` in your table `addresses`, and its type is currently `integer`, and you want to change it to `string`.

Now, it is quite possible to change the datatype from `integer` to `string`, but changing a `string` back to the integer will not always be possible, so we can't revert this migration.

```
def self.up
  change_column :address, :zipcode, :string
end
```

Now, if you do `rake db:migrate`, it will work fine, but when you are gonna revert it, you will get back the following error:

> -- Rake aborted!
>       -- ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration

---

> And what's the benefit of making them irreversible?

Actually, we do not tend to make them irreversible; it happens to be irreversible. Personally, I'd go with always reversible, because they are really flexible.